# How to ensure that Visual Studio Online Git Repository is private?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm on free 5 user plan of Team Services at [VisualStudio.com](https://www.visualstudio.com/). Could you please tell me where can I find an option or a mention that shows if the Git repositories I have are public or private?

I tried to enter a repo URL into a browser with another user logged on and got 'access denied' (as expected). But I want to be 100% sure to avoid occasions similar to [this one](https://www.humankode.com/security/how-a-bug-in-visual-studio-2015-exposed-my-source-code-on-github-and-cost-me-6500-in-a-few-hours).

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

All repositories in Visual Studio Team Services are private... They do not offer public repositories at the moment.

---

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs.aspx

> Free benefits Five users free, **unlimited private repos**, developer
>   tools, training and support

---

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/version-control-vs.aspx

> Unlimited free repos And **they're private**, too!
>
> Don't limit your development projects! Visual Studio Team Services
>   provides teams with the ability to create as many Git or TFVC repos as
>   are needed for any project.

Comment: Its been two years since this answer was posted. I can't find any conflicting information.. Still the case?

Comment: @wasatchwizard VSTS repositories are still private as of this writing.

Answer (score 10):

Visual Studio Online does not (currently) offer public repositories.

Answer (score 0):

To verify that you could go ahead and clone the git repository on some other computer using the https or ssh links and see if it prompts for the credentials. If it gets cloned without asking for the credentials, then it is not private. Why trust someone else, when you could yourself verify.